# Why renderTable() does not giving any output in shinyApp for selectInput items?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display **tabular data** while input select entered in shinyUI.

Here is my code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    dashboardBody(
      selectInput("filt", "Datafiltered",
                  choices = unique(comor$DiagnosisProvided),
                  multiple = TRUE),
      tableOutput("tab1")
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$tab1 <- renderTable({
      apl <- data %>% filter(DiagnosisProvided == input$filt)
    })
  }
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I am getting error *"Result must have length 707, not 0"*
I would like to upload my **data**. Is there any link to upload my data?

Can anyone help me on **renderTable()** output ?

Comment: Could you provide example data for `comor` and `data`? Try using `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

as you have not given any data sample to make it reproducible, I tried to built the same as per my understandings with IRIS Data. Hope this can solve your issue.

[image]

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyglide)


dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
      )
   ),
   dashboardBody(
      useShinyalert(),
      tabItems(
         tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                 fluidRow(
                        column(3,
                               uiOutput("filter")
                               ),
                        column(9,
                               tableOutput("tab")
                               )
                        )
                 )
      )
   )
)
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input,output){

####### Your data ######  

  data<-iris

 output$filter<-renderUI({
   selectInput("filter_select","Select Filter",choices = unique(data$Species))
 })

 output$tab<-renderTable({
   if(is.null(input$filter_select))
   {
     returnValue()
   }
   else
   {
     show_data<-data %>% filter(Species == input$filter_select)
     show_data
   }

 })


})
```

Comment: My problem is with :                                                                              
                  selectInput("filt", "Datafiltered",
                  choices = unique(comor$DiagnosisProvided),
                  multiple = TRUE)

Comment: Acute gastroenteritis  ||  Fever 1
Acute gastroenteritis  ||  Gastritis 1
Acute gastroenteritis  ||  Pyrexia 1
Acute gastroenteritis  ||  Seizure 1
Acute gelatinous pneumonia 2
AKI (acute kidney injury) due to trauma 1
Anemia  ||  Pyrexia  ||  URTI - Acute upper respiratory infection 1
Text in column1 and numbers are in column 2. How could I count only Anemia count? I have 3 values in one single column. I am using such column in input$DiagnosisProvided to filter. It is not getting filtered.

Comment: @krishna   can you add a sample dataset for you problem? if the above solution works i can give it a try with your dataset??

Comment: I am not finding any link through which I can upload my sample data. Can you please  guide me how to upload .csv file?

Comment: @krishna no need to upload ..you can create the same dataset in R which can satisfy the requirement condition and share the code/dataset....

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `data %>% filter(DiagnosisProvided == input$filt)`, because `input$filt` is an empty array. You can reproduce this error by:

`iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length == NULL)`
.... `Result must have length 150, not 0`

So check your `unique(comor$DiagnosisProvided)` it looks like it is empty. And then instead of using the `==` replace it by `%in%`:

`data %>% filter(DiagnosisProvided %in% input$filt)`